# Qual a melhor maneira ou método de estudar bancos noSQL?

Tags: nosql, elasticsearch, cassandra

Preciso desenvolver um script que sincronize um banco cassandra apache com um outro elastic search. Contudo, desconheço o mecanismo de funcionamento dos dois, que são bancos noSQL. Qual o meio mais rápido de me atualizar e aprender sobre os dois? Podem ser cursos, apostilas e etc.

Comment: Existe um site chamado coursera, lá têm bastante conteúdo didático sobre nosql, da ate certificado. sua pergunta aqui sobre isso fica um pouco fora do escopo.